# Update attribute value in database depending on time

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.net MVC5 and Entity Framework
Is there any way or script that allows  to auto update the column in my database everyday period of time (that may change)

Comment: write a windows service which does that. Or a console app which is scheduled to execute on a specific time using task scheduler ?

Comment: you can create SQL Server jobs , Note: you need SQL Server Agent running.

Comment: thank you @Yeou  could you give me a blog or any site could help me start with it

Comment: you can follow the steps here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have a couple of options for this

**1 a Windows Service application**, this basically runs hidden as any other service, you can see a guide here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer

**2 Create a Console Applicaton and put it in the task scheduler of the OS** this is simpler because you configure a period in windows itself and can change it whenever you want and don´t need to recompile your app. here you can see a guide https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721931(v=ws.11).aspx

**3 Create a SQL Job** if you want to do this as a DB Admin, you can create a job in SQL, this will run your script periodically as well, how to create a job in sql https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268(v=sql.110).aspx#TsqlProcedure

```
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = N'Update Clients' ;
GO
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'Update Clients',
    @step_name = N'Update IDs',
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',
    @command = N'UPDATE CLIENTS SET...', 
    @retry_attempts = 5,
    @retry_interval = 5 ;
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_schedule
    @schedule_name = N'RunDaily',
    @freq_type = 1,
    @active_start_time = 233000 ;
USE YOURDB ;
GO
EXEC sp_attach_schedule
   @job_name = N'Update Clients',
   @schedule_name = N'RunDaily';
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver
    @job_name = N'Update Clients';
GO
```

**4 You can create a PowerShell script** this is an example http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/nycnet/2013/05/24/performing-an-insert-from-a-powershell-script/ and put it in the windows task scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

I have put some steps that I think you need to follow, as you said that you need to execute some script.

1. Create new job by right clicking jobs folder in SQL Server Agent.

   [image: Create New Job]
2. Enter Name for the Job in General Page.

   [image]
3. Switch to Steps page and click New...

   [image]
4. Enter Name for the Step, Select the database against which you need to run the job and Write your script in the Command Box.

   [image]
5. Next switch to Schedules Page and create new Schedule.

   [image]
6. In Schedule Dialog, Configure the Frequency the script should run.

   [image]
7. Save the Job.
   [image]
8. You can test your job by right clicking your job and selecting `Start Job at Step...`
   [image]